# Input number with comma isn't parsed as numeric value in the data-bind, in IE

Tags: knockout.js

```
<input type="number" data-bind="value: value"/>

<h2>Value: <span data-bind="text: value"/></h2>

var ViewModel = function() {   
this.value = ko.observable();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Now, if I enter "23,45", in chrome the data-bind value will be saved as "23.45", but in Internet Explorer it will still be "23,45". Both browsers are in French and the Windows 10 I'm running is also set to French regional settings.
French uses comma for decimal separator.

So how can I make IE bind the value properly? As numeric.

Comment: I use custom binding which use numeraljs (http://numeraljs.com/) which works well in browsers and good at numbers similar to moment for date manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about just a writable computed observable http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html

```js
function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.mynumber = ko.observable();
  this.computedNumber = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function() {
      return this.mynumber()
    },
    write: function(value) {
      var n = value.replace(/,/g, ".");
      var number = (!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n)) ? n : '';
      self.mynumber(number);
    },
    owner: this
  });

}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="value: computedNumber" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This read/write format is very similar to get/set from C#, which is exactly what I was looking for.